# What is the difference between node's bodyParser and express's urlencoded middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, urlencode, body-parser

After reading about both i still can't wrap my head about it,
could be language differences bu please help clarify.

`express.urlencoded()`

> Returns middleware that only parses urlencoded bodies and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts only UTF-8 encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

And

and `body-parser` middleware

> Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers, available under the req.body property.

i understand that `express.urlencoded` is based on Nodejs `body-parser`.
and both pages,

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded

and

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

even say the same warning note:

> As req.body’s shape is based on user-controlled input, all properties and values in this object are untrusted and should be validated before trusting. For example, req.body.foo.toString() may fail in multiple ways, for example foo may not be there or may not be a string, and toString may not be a function and instead a string or other user-input.

but eventually both give me a `req.body` with params sent in requests body object. so why should i use body-parser (which i have to install separatly) instead of always using `express.urlencoded()`

I know this isn't a code problem but i thank in advance for anyone who can list up to the main differences.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> so why should i use body-parser (which i have to install separatly) instead of always using express.urlencoded()

For the simple reason that it was not available in older version of express

> This middleware is available in Express v4.16.0 onwards.

If you're using the latest version, there's almost no reason to.

`body-parser` provides a few additional utilities like `bodyParser.raw([options])` or `bodyParser.text([options])` which almost nobody uses (never seen use one myself).

Comment: Oh! Thank you for a smiple yet very undestandable answer! :D So i imagine that even-though i'm using the latest express version and there isn't really a reason to install `body-parser` there is still a change of dependencies fails (like what i'm experiencing with PassportJS which after investigating seems it misses the body parser even though i have the `urlencoded` middleware on. could be?)

Comment: passportjs have only 2 dependencies listed `passport-strategy`, `pause`, it could be from other packages depding on `body-parser`

Comment: Great! Thanks i'll keep looking. but as i understand from your answer and comment. there could be dependencies failures. which brings up a reliability problem with `urlencoded()` for me and makes me wonder if it's just good to always include `body-parser` instead of `urlencoded` just to be safe always. I mean i'ts a node module after all. It's too reliable by it self. @naga - elixir - jar Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: now `express` have `body-parser` as `dependencies`, so it should automatically download `body-parser` when you run `npm install express`. Not sure why you need to re-download

Comment: It might just be that the `body parser` isn't really my problem in my code. it just led me to investigate about it and just couldn't tell the diff. :) i'll keep looking